# Read a directory of CSV files in R

Tags: file, csv, r

I'm writing a lot of R in my spare time and am trying to get into good habits by using TidyVerse as much as possible. A large part of this has required reading entire directories of dated log files into R for processing. The volumes of data are well into the GBs so I won't post one here and it shouldn't matter so long as you have filenames matching "./accounts_20180217.csv" or "./symbols_20180217.csv" in the working or data directory.

Example file contents is:

#### ./accounts_20180217.csv

```
 16 109=18A
175 109=1FN    
 10 109=ABP
  6 109=ABW
787 109=ACI
226 109=ACL
163 109=AD
644 109=AGM
 79 109=AGN
 40 109=AIG
  2 109=AJT
991 109=ALG
  4 109=ALGR
 14 109=AM1
 17 109=AN1
 34 109=AP1
136 109=APA
267 109=APJ    
160 109=ARE
 64 109=ARX
329 109=AS1
```

I've been using the following to read in and categorise the file data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

all_data <- tibble(
              filename = list.files(
                   "./", pattern = "^(accounts|symbols)_201[7-9][0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}\\.csv$"
               , full.names = TRUE
              )
            ) %>%
            mutate(
              date = str_extract(filename, "201[7-9][0-9]{4}")
              , type = str_extract(filename, "(accounts|symbols)")
              , data = map2(
                      filename
                      , date
                      , ~read.csv(
                           .x
                           , header = FALSE
                           , sep = "="
                           , as.is = TRUE
                           , col.names = c("count", "names")
                           , colClasses = c("integer", "character") ))
  )
```

My question is whether this is a good and Tidy way to achieve this or is there a "better" or "Tidier" way?

Comment: What are you planing to do with these tables after reading them?

Comment: @Hugh they get pivoted and sliced and diced then graphed in various ways to demonstrate message flow statistics to a customer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A consistent `tidyverse` solution would use `readr::read_csv` I guess.

You don't need `map2` if you don't use `.y`, `map` is enough.

You can use `read.csv` as your `.f` argument, and leave the rest to the `...` in your `map` call, might be a matter of taste but I prefer it that way as with the formula notation you have to read through to make sure `read.csv` is the only function called.

`as.is` doesn't seem necessary if you give column classes already.

Your `mutate` call is not necessary, `tibble` will evaluate lazily the definition of `filename` given at the previous step.

It seems you really want a "one liner" but in my opinion it would be much clearer in a few steps, I propose the following:

```
files <- list.files(
  "./",
  full.names = TRUE,
  pattern = "^(accounts|symbols)_201[7-9][0-9]{4}\\.csv$")

data_lst <- map(
  files, 
  read_csv,
  header = FALSE,
  sep = "=",
  coltypes = "ic",
  col_names = c("count", "names"))

tibble(
  file_name = files,
  date = str_extract(filename, "201[7-9][0-9]{4}"),
  type = str_extract(filename, "(accounts|symbols)"),
  data = data_lst)
```

In fact as you're working with a lot of data files I'd tend to write a for loop instead of a `map` call, so I could more easily debug and proceed without restarting all if an issue arises.

Comment: Just so you know I did know that I need to move to read_csv and have done in other projects. Also I hadn't spotted that map2 error so thanks!

Comment: +1 but I won't accept the answer for a few days to allow others to answer since R on Code Review SO isn't exactly epically followed

Comment: Indeed, and it's a shame considering how people fight for answers on SO... Take your time ;)